# Ms Access List Box - Pass parameter on Double click to a new form

Tags: vba, ms-access

**I have a listbox in Microsoft Access 2010**

[image]

**I am trying to pass all parameters to a new form(frmpopUpPatientInfo) on double click of a record, example when I click on Patient:21, it should pass 21, Clinton, bill to new form.
What i tried is below where `lstEvents` is listbox name, `frmCalendar` is the parent form**

```
Private Sub lstEvents_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmpopUpPatientInfo"

    MsgBox Me.Parent.frmCalendar.lstEvents.Column(1), vbInformation, "Test"

End Sub
```

**The Error i am getting is**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Forms!frmCalendar!lstEvents.Column(1)
```

https://www.599cd.com/tips/access/forms-formname-field-notation/

Comment: This worked 

DoCmd.OpenForm "frmpopUpPatientInfo", acNormal, , , , , Forms!frmCalendar!lstEvents.Column(0)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to pass to a NEW form that was opened, you should not be using the 'Parent....' reference.

Below are two methods of passing data to a form.

```
' Pass arguments when the form is opened
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmpopUpPatientInfo", acNormal, , , , , Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY")
' Or reference a control as follows:
Forms!frmpopUpPatientInfo.myTargetField= Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY")
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked

DoCmd.OpenForm "frmpopUpPatientInfo", acNormal, , , , , Forms!frmCalendar!lstEvents.Column(0)